# What does a BitWise OR ("|") mean when used with a return statement?

Tags: c#, return, bit-manipulation

In C#.NET, has anyone ever seen a return statement inside a method that looks like this?

```
protected override Buttons GetButtonsToShow()
{
    return Buttons.New | Buttons.Return | Buttons.Delete;
}
```

How is this BitWise operator "|" working here? What is the result of this statement? I know how the BitWise operators work in if ... else ... statements and such, but I've never seen it used this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Buttons` is a [flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx).

This makes it bit-mappable where you can use bitwise operators to combine values.

In this case it will returns a value that is a bitmap combining all of the three options.

[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/wim/archive/2004/04/07/109095.aspx) blog post has quite a clear explanation (though it uses `&` for the example).

Comment: Thank you, Oded. It will take me a little bit to fully grasp the information in that blog, but I'm sure it will be really helpful.

Comment: @campbelt - The main concept to understand is what the `FlagsAttribute` does and thinking in binary (after all, binary is why one uses bitwise operators).

Answer (score 1):

Logically such methods return set of flags (the enum is marked with `Flags` attribute). Later you can check whether a certain flag is set using bitwise `&`.

In this particular example, somewhere there is code that checks whether to show a certain button. Something like this:

```
Buttons buttons = GetButtonsToShow();

bool showNewButton = (buttons & Buttons.New) != 0;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This is in alignment with Oded's response as well, and with the blog post he referenced. I'm going to review that blog to see if I can wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

If you break down this expression it will become more clear:

```
protected override Buttons GetButtonsToShow()
{
    var returnValue = Buttons.New | Buttons.Return | Buttons.Delete;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Can you see it now?

The operator | does not alter the return statement itself. The result of the `Buttons.New | Buttons.Return | Buttons.Delete` expression is returned by the function.

Comment: Are you sure that is the case? I'm totally new here, so I could certainly be wrong, but I am not sure this works like a conditional statement in that way, if that is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

It is performing the bitwise operations and using the result as the return value. Buttons is an enumeration that has the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) applied to it and looks something like the following:

```
[Flags]
public enum Buttons
{
    New = 1,
    Return = 2,
    Delete = 4
}
```

The usage of the return value from your GetButtonsToShow() method would be something like this:

```
private void DisplayButtons()
{
    var buttons = GetButtonsToShow(); // int value is 7, 1 + 2 + 4

    if ((buttons & Buttons.New) == Buttons.New) // if 7 (111) and 1 (001) equals 1 
    {
        buttonNew.Visible = true;
    }

    // above is for clarity, most likely all buttons visibility is set as:
    // buttonX.Visible = (buttons & Buttons.X) == Buttons.X;
}
```